# In coldFusion CFFTP, existsDir generate error if dir doesn't exist

Tags: coldfusion, ftp, coldfusion-10

I am using `existsDir` to check if a folder exists or not.

```
<cfftp action="existsDir" 
       connection="FTP" 
       directory="/Download/Test">
#cfftp.returnvalue#
```

If the folder exists, then everything works fine. The `returnvalue` is "yes". If the folder doesn't exist, then the `existsDir` action fails with the following error:

```
An error occurred during the sFTP existsDir operation. The system cannot find the path /Download/Test
```

The whole point of this action is to determine whether a folder exists. Yet it is causing an error if it doesn't exist. Am I missing something?

I can add try and catch around this whole statement (i am going add it anyway just to be safe), but that would make this existDir pointless.

Comment: According to [the docs](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/cfftp%3A+Connection%3A+file+and+directory+operations) that should be good. Is this wrapped in a function? Are you adding any other attributes?

Comment: Obviously you can surround your code with a `<cftry> <cfcatch>` block to gracefully catch the error but this sounds like a bug to me. Please enter one - https://bugbase.adobe.com/

Answer (score 2):

I experienced this also. Seems to be a bug alright even in CF 2016 (which we just migrated to). I got around it by setting stoponerror="No" during the cfftp action="existsDir" usage like this;

```
<cfftp action="existsDir"
       connection="ftp_connection"
       directory="#remote_path#"
       stoponerror="No">
```

You can then just check if it 'succeeded' and create the Dir if necessary;

```
<cfif cfftp.succeeded NEQ "YES">

    <!--- Create directory --->
    <cfftp action="createDir"
         connection="ftp_connection"
         directory="#remote_path#"
         stoponerror="No">
</cfif>
```